# Can we omit "that" after "definite" as in "It is definite he will go today"?

Tags: word-usage

After "certain", we can omit "that." For example, we can say "It's certain he will go today." Do you think we can omit "that" after "definite" too? On dictionaries, there is no example of omiting "that" after "definite". So I had to ask you. For example, can we say, "It is definite he will go today" instead of "It is definite that he will go today"?

Comment: It is optional, but I would keep it in.

Comment: The problem is that most people *would not go around saying that*. They'd more likely say: He's definitely going today.

Comment: [in dictionaries, not on them. for your correction pleasure.]

Comment: @Lambie I thought it could be correct to use "on" because I was talking about web dictionaries.

Comment: @Lambie Thank you for your comment, but I think you always focus on the example rather than the main question.

Comment: Everything between [...] is for you to correct. If I correct it, you won't learn it. And when you correct it, I shall delete my comment.

Comment: Adding to Lambie's comment, one might also say "He will definitely go today".